# Building SpiderMonkey with Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, spidermonkey

I need to build SpiderMonkey so that I can use it with emscripten. I succeeded in building version 1.8 (using the hack from here: http://pmelson.blogspot.fr/2007/12/building-didier-stevens-spidermonkey-in.html). But unfortunately version 1.8 lacks JSON support and apparently that came into existance with version 1.8.1.

Unfortunately I don't see any 1.8.1 tag/branch in CVS and I cannot use version 1.8.5 because the above hack no longer works with that version.

Any ideas for getting this to work in Cygwin?

Comment: You don't need a hack for 1.8.5; it is available in the Cygwin distro as libmozjs185-devel.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that next time.. this time I had finally used VisualC++ to do it all without Cygwin..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following guide for building Spidermonkey in Cygwin.

[SpiderMonkey Build Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Build_Documentation)

[Windows build prerequisites](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Developer_Guide/Build_Instructions/Windows_Prerequisites)

I have used the instructions to build the 1.8.5 version and it worked fine.